# NodeJS Express Socket.io Impletation in a Seperate File

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io, maintainability

I am using [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/en/) [Express v4](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/migrating-4.html) and [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for implementing WebSocket.

My **app.js** is like this-

```
var express = require('express');
var socket_io = require( "socket.io" );
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
//var controllers = require('./controllers');
//var middleware = require('./middleware');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Express
var app          = express();

// Socket.io
var io           = socket_io();
app.io           = io;

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('view options', { layout: false });     //Disabling default layout
require('./view_partials')(app);

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

require('./routes')(app);

//// Socket.io server listens to our app

    //Server - Data received
        // Send current time to all connected clients
        function sendTime()
        {
            io.emit('time', { time: new Date().toJSON() });
        }

        // Send current time every 10 secs
        setInterval(sendTime, 10000);

    //Client - Data received
        // Emit welcome message on connection
        io.on('connection', function(socket)
        {
            // Use socket to communicate with this particular client only, sending it it's own id
            socket.emit('welcome', { message: 'Welcome!', id: socket.id });
            socket.on('i am client', console.log);
        });
////////////////////////////////////////

require('./errors')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

I like to export this code-

```
    //Client - Data received
        // Emit welcome message on connection
        io.on('connection', function(socket)
        {
            // Use socket to communicate with this particular client only, sending it it's own id
            socket.emit('welcome', { message: 'Welcome!', id: socket.id });
            socket.on('i am client', console.log);
        });
```

to a new file.

So, what I have done is like this-

**client.js**-

```
//Client - Data received
    // Emit welcome message on connection
    io.on('connection', function(socket)
    {
        // Use socket to communicate with this particular client only, sending it it's own id
        socket.emit('welcome', { message: 'Welcome!', id: socket.id });
        socket.on('i am client', console.log);
    });
```

**app.js**-

```
var express = require('express');
var socket_io = require( "socket.io" );
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
//var controllers = require('./controllers');
//var middleware = require('./middleware');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Express
var app          = express();

// Socket.io
var io           = socket_io();
app.io           = io;

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('view options', { layout: false });     //Disabling default layout
require('./view_partials')(app);

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

require('./routes')(app);

//// Socket.io server listens to our app

    //Server - Data received
        // Send current time to all connected clients
        function sendTime()
        {
            io.emit('time', { time: new Date().toJSON() });
        }

        // Send current time every 10 secs
        setInterval(sendTime, 10000);

    require('./websocket/client');
////////////////////////////////////////

require('./errors')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

But is is neither giving me an error or not working.

Can anyone please help, how can I export that in a separate file so that client and server code can be separated?

My full code can be found [**here**](https://github.com/abrarjahin/express-hbs).

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem. We need to share the `io` variable to include file.

In **app.js** -

```
require('./websocket/server')(io);
```

And **./websocket/server.js** -

```
// Socket.io server listens to our app
module.exports = function(io)
{
    // Send current time to all connected clients
    function sendTime()
    {
        io.emit('time', { time: new Date().toJSON() });
    }
    // Send current time every 10 secs
    setInterval(sendTime, 10000);
}
```

Everything is working :).

Answer (score -1):

From http://socket.io/get-started/chat/:

> Socket.IO is composed of two parts
>
> - A server that integrates with (or mounts on) the Node.JS HTTP Server: socket.io
> - A client library that loads on the browser side: socket.io-client

You write handlers/emitters for sockets on both the server and the client. The client-side handlers/emitters must be included in the client-side javascript for client browsers to be able to access them. Client-side javascript is always in a separate file from your server-side code.

You can check the Socket.IO getting started tutorial linked above for more information.

As a simple example, here is what you would put in your server code (your **`app.js`**). This code listens for new client connections, then emits a `welcome` event to the connected client.

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http)

// Listen for socket events
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // a client has connected!
    // emit a message to it
    var msg = "Hello client!"
    socket.emit('welcome', msg);
});
```

And here is what would go on the client (**`client.js`**):

```
var socket = io();

// add event listeners to the socket
// on 'welcome' event, log the response to console
socket.on('welcome', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    // Hello client!
});
```

Comment: Hi, what you are saying is a general concept which is common and everybody knows. if you want to help, please answer my specific question. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I must not have fully understood your question.